# adding .value stops flow of javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, css-selectors

I'm in the middle of creating a program in the browser which compares the selections of the user with a list of pre-defined holidays using Objects. I tried to create an object from the selections of the user to use in comparisons and select the most matching holiday, however when I try to select the value (adding .value) it seems to break the flow of Java, and none of the code read afterwards is read.

```
var climateVar = document.getElementById('climateselect')/.value\;
var accVar = document.getElementById('accomadationselect')/.value\;
var durationVar = document.getElementById('duration')/.value\;

var userInput = new Input(climateVar/.value\, accVar/.value\, durationVar/.value\);

for (var key in userInput) {
    var woo = userInput[key];
    document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML += woo/.value\;

}
```

without any .value/s, this prints[object HTMLSelectElement]null[object HTMLSelectElement] -                            (I changed "getElementById" to "querySelector" which simply made it print "nullnullnull")
, but when I try to add .value anywhere, the entire script stops working, and so everything under this will not run. Why on earth would adding .value stop the script from working? Nothing else changed.

Also, I'm a novice at this, this was meant to be a practice project, but I've been stuck on this for about a day now. any other advice you might feel like giving would also be appreciated

everywhere I typed /.value\ I've tried to add .value, and it has had the effect of stopping the code

Comment: will you please share your HTML?

Comment: Chances are you will be getting an error, check the console (Hit F12, look for console)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are calling value on a valid object? The object has to exist and support .value to get a result -  e.g.

http://jsfiddle.net/pherris/t57ktnLk/

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="123"/>
<div id="divHoldingInfo">123</div>
```

JavaScript

```
alert(document.getElementById('textInput').value);
alert(document.getElementById('divHoldingInfo').innerHTML);
alert(document.getElementById('iDontExist').value); //errors out
```